# Error in Code Example: "Can only recur from tail position"

Tags: clojure, channel

The follwing function implements mapping functionality using channels, similar to the behavoiur of the normal clojure [map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map)

I got this code example from the book *Seven concurrency models in seven weeks* by Paul Butcher. It seems that this code is already outdated because when executing it, it throws the follwing error message. Does anyone know how to fix the function?

**Error Message:**

> Can only recur from tail position {:exprs nil, :form (recur)

**Code:**

```
   (defn map-chan [f from]
    (let [to (chan)]
     (go-loop []
      (when-let [x (<! from)]
       (>! to (f x))
       (recur))
     (close! to))
    to))
```

**My first fixing attempt:** // same error as origin

```
(defn map-chan [f from]
  (go-loop []
         (do
          (let [to (chan)]
          (when-let [x (<! from)]
           (>! to (f x))
           (recur))))
          (close! to)
         )
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it does not work; this is also mentioned in the [errata to the book](https://pragprog.com/titles/pb7con/errata).

You can place the `close!` function call outside the loop to ensure that  `recur` is in final position (note that you have to use `go` and `loop` instead of `go-loop` for that):

```
(defn map-chan [f from]
  (let [to (chan)]
    (go (loop []
          (when-let [x (<! from)]
            (>! to (f x))
            (recur)))
        (close! to))
    to))
```